# SQL: Split Dataset into two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
 id  c_id  time  value
  1     4     1     12
  2     4     2      5
  3     4     3      6
  4     4     4     48
  5     4     5      1 
  6     4     6    121 
  7     5     1    121 
  8     5     2    321 
  9     5     3      2 
 10     5     4      1 
 11     5     5     54 
 12     5     6   4546   
 13     5     7     78 
 14     5     8    784 
 15     5     9      1
```

Now I want a table like this with a `SELECT` command:

```
time1  value1  time2  value2
    1      12      1     121
    2       5      2     321
    3       6      3       2
    4      48      4       1
    5       1      5      54
    6     121      6    4546
    0       0      7      78
    0       0      8     784
    0       0      9       1
```

`time1` and `value1` is from the data with `c_id=4`,
`time2` and `value2` is from the data with `c_id=5`

Is it possible to create a `SELECT` command to do that?

I hope you can help

Comment: Please, text - not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yiu can use an inner join

```
select a.time as time1, a.value as value1, b.time as time2, b.value as value2
from my_table as a 
inner join my_table as b on a.time = b.time
and a.c_id= 4
and b.c_id= 5;
```

Comment: With a.id = b.id it doesn't work - I had to change it into a.time=b.time. But your code helped me a lot! Thx man!

Comment: `a.time=b.time` will not display all records of c_id 5. it will display records upto 6 because c_id 4 has records upto 6 only

Comment: Yeah I know. And this isn't optimal, but with `a.id=b.id` it shows nothing... I have no other idea what criteria I should use...